# How to use custom shapefiles in OpenTripPlanner?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I have some `.shp` files and I wanted to try to use them in Open Trip Planner. I run the command:

`java -Xmx2G -jar otp-0.20.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build /path/to/my/shapefile/ --inMemory`

but I get the following errors:

```
18:17:45.617 WARN (GraphBuilder.java:224) Skipping unrecognized file '/path/to/my/shapefile/shapefile.dbf'
18:17:45.617 WARN (GraphBuilder.java:224) Skipping unrecognized file '/path/to/my/shapefile/shapefile.prj'
18:17:45.618 WARN (GraphBuilder.java:224) Skipping unrecognized file '/path/to/my/shapefile/shapefile.shp'
18:17:45.618 WARN (GraphBuilder.java:224) Skipping unrecognized file '/path/to/my/shapefile/shapefile.shx'
18:17:45.618 ERROR (GraphBuilder.java:230) Found no input files from which to build a graph in /path/to/my/shapefile/
18:17:45.618 ERROR (OTPMain.java:122) An error occurred while building the graph. Exiting.
```

How do I import them? Or I need to convert it to `osm`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using a transform method with a jar

http://developer.onebusaway.org/modules/onebusaway-gtfs-modules/current-SNAPSHOT/onebusaway-gtfs-transformer-cli.html#Merge_Trips_and_Refactor_Calendar_Entries